# Why jump instead of return in Java bytecode?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

### Background

I compiled the following method:

```java
public static final boolean equalTo(final int x, final int y) {
    return x == y;
}
```

And with `javap` could see that the following bytecode was produced for it:

```
  public static final boolean equalTo(int, int);                                                                                                                                                                 
    descriptor: (II)Z                                                                                                                                                                                            
    flags: (0x0019) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL                                                                                                                                                            
    Code:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2                                                                                                                                                                             
         0: iload_0                                                                                                                                                                                              
         1: iload_1                                                                                                                                                                                              
         2: if_icmpne     9                                                                                                                                                                                      
         5: iconst_1                                                                                                                                                                                             
         6: goto          10                                                                                                                                                                                     
         9: iconst_0                                                                                                                                                                                             
        10: ireturn                                                                                                                                                                                              
      LineNumberTable:                                                                                                                                                                                           
        line 72: 0                                                                                                                                                                                               
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2                                                                                                                                                                       
        frame_type = 9 /* same */                                                                                                                                                                                
        frame_type = 64 /* same_locals_1_stack_item */                                                                                                                                                           
          stack = [ int ]
```

I wrote [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) that would create the same bytecode, and also created another version that behaved the same by changing the `goto 10` to an `ireturn`. It's negligible, but this also reduces the size of the `StackMapTable` since it eliminates a jump.

### Question

I know "it's only bytecode" and not indicative of what the machine will do, but why does the compiler emit `goto 10` when it could simply emit `ireturn`?

Comment: Just speculating (hence not posting as an answer), but `x == y` is an expression in its own right; the `return` is just returning the result of the expression. Bytecode isn't particularly optimized, it doesn't surprise me to see it output the instructions for the `x == y` expression, followed separately by the instruction for `return`. Combining them, looking at context to see that the result of the expression is being returned, would be more work for `javac`. The JIT will turn it into something efficient if necessary.

Comment: Keep in mind that `javac` does effectively no optimizations (with the only exception that comes to my mind being constant folding as described in the JLS). All optimizations like this are done at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frontend compilers generate code using simple patterns, and they rely on optimization passes to clean things up. At the point that the `x == y` expression is generated, the compiler doesn't "know" that the very next thing is a return statement. It could potentially check this, but that extra step can be handled just as easily with some sort of peephole optimizer.

The benefit of a peephole optimizer is that it can perform cascading optimizations, that is, the result of one optimization can feed into the next one. The code that generated the `x == y` expression doesn't really have any way of performing anything more than one optimization step without adding more complexity.

The java compiler used to have an optimization feature, but this was ditched in favor of HotSpot, which can perform even more powerful optimizations. Performing optimizations in the java compiler would slow it down and not really improve things all that much.